# Django. Pre-processing data from DB

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to add some additional information for data returned from DB. For example there is 'name' field in DB for Person and I need to add '{', '}' to it when it is showed on form. I thought that method bound_data of 'Field' class from 'django.forms.fields' module is what I need. But seems that it serves for other purposes. It works when form was submitted and failed validation for any reason - just to not lose data that was correct.

So how can I implement some decorating for my 'name' field?

Comment: Are you looking to change the data that is returned by the database, the data that is saved to the database, or the way that the data is presented if and only if that data is presented inside of a form?

Comment: The third one - the way that the data is presented if and only if that data is presented inside of a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain in what situation you need it. I was have the similar problem and I solve it inside **unicode**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s,' % self.name
```

Now inside form you will have unicode for the model and when you need just the name you use person.name instead. Hope it helps.

Comment: How could I forget about __unicode__? Don't know. It perfectly solves one of my problems. Thanks.

Comment: In my case I want to decorate 2 fields. I think __unicode__ won't help me.

Answer (score 2):

I found in Field class of 'django.forms.fields' module the method 'prepare_value' which does some manipulation with data from DB or with some initial data for field. So I overrode this method in 'MyField' and placed all decoration work in it. It allow you to work with more than one fields of model, so guess it's better than **unicode** method.

But still thank Goran.

Comment: upvote this. I found this magic method reading forms/forms.py, and it's the right solution.